# How to set up a BIND DNS server to respond a single IP address to any request on Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2008, bind, domain-name-system, a-record

I want to configure a BIND DNS server (since Windows Web Server 2008 does not have DNS service, I had to install BIND) that responds any request with a single `A record`. I had set up a `*` record but it seems to work just for direct subdomains of the server. I mean `subdomain.xyz.com` will be responded correctly, but `subdomain2.subdomain1.xyz.com` is not. I might have screwed up the config files as have just worked with MS DNS before.

Can you tell me how to configure BIND from the beginning to resolve every requested address with a constant IP address?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

In `named.conf`:

```
options {
    recursion yes;
}

zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "named.root";
};
```

In "named.root":

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 1D
@    IN     SOA  @ none. ( 0 1D 1H 1W 3H );
     IN     NS   @
*    IN     A    a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Without any SOA record?

Comment: full (and tested) info now included...

Comment: (I wasn't sure until I tested it how little information I could get away with supplying to Bind)

Comment: sorry to bring up this old thread.
but i just test this and seems it did not work.
any updated info? especially for debian lenny.

should i just ask new question?

tnx

Comment: define "did not work".