# split dns for google

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, google, nsd

how to setup any dns (prefer nsd3) to give ip 1.2.3.4 for google and 2.3.4.5 for all others?

Comment: all google domains, or just google.com?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about NSD, but with BIND9's `view` clause you could create a view matching only Google's IP addresses.

[DNS for Rocket Scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/) contain a section covering them: [DNS BIND view Clause](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/view.html).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you're looking for the answer to depend on the source IP address, which is what's normally known as a "view", or "split DNS".

If I understand you correctly, you want to *serve* the answer '1.2.3.4' if the question is Google, and '2.3.4.5' if the question is anything else.

For a BIND answer, see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/2283/how-to-set-up-a-bind-dns-server-to-respond-a-single-ip-address-to-any-request-on) setting the wildcard to your '2.3.4.5' and just add specific records to override the wildcard for those domains that you want to resolve to '1.2.3.4'.

Alternatively, my [evldns](http://code.google.com/p/evldns/) software could easily do this.