# setup dns to redirect all http requests on a specific machine in LAN

Tags: domain-name-system, http

i should set up the following configuration with 2 machines: 
machine A issues HTTP requests
machine B serves the pages requested by A

For testing purposes, i want that EVERY HTTP request issued by machine A gets served by machine B.

For example, machine A browser tries to access www.website.com/article.php?1234

machine B has a folder in its http server that has the content and replies to A.

How can I set up a dns on machine B to point ALL requests to itself?

Thanks

Comment: First of all, with DNS changes only you won't be able to selectively redirect all HTTP request (and leave other types of traffic alone). Second, what's your current setup - is B your current local DNS server for all the machines (A)? Is it a gateway/router? Your best bet would be probably to use some redirection at the firewall level.

Comment: hi karol, i'd like to redirect all traffic. machine A won't have internet access, it will only reach pages on machine B. 
B will be set up for this purpose alone and it is not a dns server yet. Should i reconsider my design?

Comment: I think some transparent proxy could do in this case. Do you want to redirect every possible domain name this way, or some special subset you have? Failover to real Internet content when not available locally? And last thing - what operating system are we talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a BIND server on either machine following the settings given in my answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/2283/how-to-set-up-a-bind-dns-server-to-respond-a-single-ip-address-to-any-request-on).

Then just make sure that machine A's DNS settings point at that DNS server.

Note (as per @Karol's comment) that this will make *all* traffic from machine A hit machine B, not just HTTP traffic.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to do as you described. Yes, i just need all traffic redirected to machine B, that will serve files from its apache server. It is just for testing purposes, so it's not required a failover to the internet. I am running desktop ubuntu 10.04

Comment: I configured like you suggested and i see from the bind9 log on B that requests arrive from machine A. But as i do a dns lookup from A with dig www.anysite.com i get a reply with status: SERVFAIL. i really can't figure out what's wrong, since i am a total newbie.

Comment: check the BIND logs on server B to find out why it's returning that.  It might be ACL related.